# PHP IF Statement - Two Variables Not Working

Tags: php, if-statement

I have an IF statement and I need to check two variables, then execute the action if either of the variables are false.

I know I can use the OR (||) statement however for some reason it is not working. I am in the process of learning PHP so it's probably a syntax error on my behalf.

If I create the if statement with only one (either) variable, it works fine:

```
<?php if ($var1 == false) { do whatever...} ?>
```

However when I try to check two, neither of the variables seem to be checked. I have tried different syntax variations but nothing works:

```
<?php if (($var1 == false) || ($var2 == false)) { do whatever...} ?>
<?php if (($var1 == false) OR ($var2 == false)) { do whatever...} ?>
<?php if ($var1 == false || $var2 == false) { do whatever...} ?>
<?php if ($var1 == false OR $var2 == false) { do whatever...} ?>
```

Can someone please point out what my error is?

Thanks!

EDIT: Including the actual code.

```
<?php $member = $members_template->member; $bpmember = bp_get_member_user_id(); ?>

                <?php $membersearchinclude = xprofile_get_field_data( 'Exclude yourself from website search results?', $bpmember ); ?>
                <?php $adminsearchinclude = xprofile_get_field_data( 'Exclude From Search Results', $bpmember ); ?>
                <?php if (($adminsearchinclude == false) || ($membersearchinclude == false)) { ?>
```

This is extracting the xprofile field state from two different checkboxes in BuddyPress. I am checking if either of the checkboxes are false, then executing code.

Comment: all 4 of those are valid http://ideone.com/6mccU7

Comment: Thats what I thought, but I figured it may be something else that I am not aware of.

Comment: perhaps if you shared your REAL code we could help

Comment: try display the values of variables

Comment: If you made an `if else` statement in the `else` part you could check which values $var1 and $var2 had.

Comment: What makes you think that they are not being checked? to be sure, right before the `if (...` add the line: `echo'<pre>';var_dump(array($var1, $var2));echo'</pre>';` and post the output

Comment: you know you dont have to swrap each lime with `<?php  ?>` debug: `var_dump($adminsearchinclude);  var_dump($membersearchinclude);`

Comment: @ChrisO'Kelly Output as requested: array (size=2)
  0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string '' (length=0)

Comment: an empty string evaluates to false, so if that is the dump of the same two variables you are checking, and you are checking them exactly like `if (($var1 == false) || ($var2 == false))`, then the code would be run. Try changing your debug output to: `echo'<pre>';var_dump(array($var1, $var2, (($var1 == false) || ($var2 == false))));echo'</pre>'`, to see what the result of your conditional is.

Comment: what's the value inside $adminsearchinclude?

Comment: @sdexp is right - add some output in an else branch of that condition and see if it runs. At this point I think it's more likely that the code inside the 'then' branch is failing for some other reason to produce output.

Comment: @ChrisO'Kelly 2nd output as requested: array (size=3)
  0 => null
  1 => null
  2 => boolean true

Comment: well there you go, the condition evaluates to true. the conditional code will 100% be getting executed. you're gonna need to post the actual contents of the 'then' branch if anyone is to help you find the real problem here. Also confusing is that what was originally an empty string is now null...

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve the issue. 
It seems my logical operators needed changing:

```
if ((!$adminsearchexclude) && (!$membersearchexclude))
```

I am sure if I posted the entire code one of you would have got it. This is a sensitive project at the moment at unfortunately posting the entire code wasn't an option.

Many thanks to everyone that chipped in especially @ChrisO'Kelly for the var dump snippets. You got me thinking in the right direction and I now have a new tool in my arsenal :)

THANK YOU ALL!!

Comment: well if you dont know the difference between AND and OR your kind of in trouble

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what causing it to not run as expected because from my view its all valid. Try to post your code so we know the whole logic.

Try to use strict comparison.

```
$var1 = 0;
$var2 = 1;

// The echo will not be executed
if ($var1 === false || $var2 === false) {
    echo "Strict comparison\n";
}

// The echo will be executed
if ($var1 == false || $var2 == false) {
    echo "No strict comparison\n";
}
```

References:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: yes, my bad. My reputation is not enough to post a comment to ask the OP to share the actual code.